# WPF ListView columns dont update thair width in time

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Hi i have a a ListView with a GridView View

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView.......
```

And in it i have a few GridViewColumn's i want the width of the columns to size to the largest item.. but this does not work, it seems on the databind it does not update the column size but instead uses the previous databind's largest item..

i have a few styles that modify the layout:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1.000001"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Style.Resources>
        <!-- Foreground for Selected ListViewItem -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" 
                                Color="Black"/>
        <!-- Background for Selected ListViewItem -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                                Color="Transparent"/>

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Margin="2,0">
                    <Rectangle x:Name="normal" />

                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContent" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                        Margin="5" 
                                        RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

does any one know why wpf behaves this way? and is there any solution?